# How to avoid react-i18next blinking?

Tags: react-i18next

Here is my code:

```
import {translate, Trans} from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from '../i18n';

const Index = () => (
    <div>
      <p>Hello Next.js</p>
    </div>
  )


export default translate(['myjson'], { i18n, wait: process.browser })(Index);
```

Here is the result:

[image]